# Glob pattern for replacing two or more spaces followed by some text within a string

Tags: bash

I want to construct a glob pattern that matches two spaces or more followed by some text on a line of text for pattern replacement.

For instance, consider the following string

```
str="Here is a list of functions  Marionette Recutils"
```

I want to replace the last part consisting of two or more spaces followed by some text.  That in a glob pattern matching `"  Marionette Recutils"`.

I want a pattern that matches two or more spaces followed by some text.
Have come up with the following pattern

```
ptrn="[[:blank:]]+([[:blank:]])+([[:graph:]])"
```

Can the pattern for parameter substitution match a substring, allowing both leading and trailing characters to exist?

Comment: If you need to merge your account with any or all of your previous accounts, then please use the [Contact](https://unix.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page to request this.  This would be preferable to create new accounts every few months.

Comment: Do you want to use `[:blank:]` because you may have other blank characters besides spaces (e.g. tabs) delimiting your string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two or more of something, with glob patterns, you can use:

- `{2,}(something)` in ksh93
- `(something)(#c2,)` in `zsh -o extendedglob`.
- `something(something)##` in `zsh -o extendedglob`.
- `something+(something)` in `ksh` or `bash -O extglob` (or `zsh --emulate ksh`).
- `somethingsomething*(something)` in those as well.

So in bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
str="Here is a list of functions  Marionette Recutils"
newstr=${str/ +( )*/REPLACEMENT}
```

Or

```
newstr=${str/[[:blank:]]+([[:blank:]])*/REPLACEMENT}
```

In POSIX sh, you could also do:

```
case str in
  (*[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*) newstr=${str%%[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*}REPLACEMENT;;
  (*) newstr=$str;;
esac
```

The `${str%%pattern}` operator (initially from ksh) removes the longest string that matches the pattern at the end of `$str`.

Comment: of course instead of `${str/ +( )*/REPLACEMENT}` one could just use `${str/  */REPLACEMENT}` (space-space-asterisk) since the `*` there matches any spaces too

Comment: @ilkkachu, yes, like in the POSIX sh approach. My point was to show how to do 2-or-more, but you're making a very good one, worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain this will not handle several edge cases, but I was successful with this...

```
# echo "Here is a list of functions  Marionette Recutils" | sed "s/  .*//"

Here is a list of functions
```

Comment: Would you know what is wrong with `ptrn="([[:blank:]]{2,}).*"` ?

Comment: I have been doing parameter replacement as `vl=${vl//${ptrn}/}`.  Which fails with `ptrn="  .*"`, but works with `ptrn="  *"`.

Comment: @Randy You are trying to use a regular expression where the shell expects a globbing pattern. If you want to clarify your question, then please do so by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Brief:** In Pure Bash: `out=${str/*  /}`

**Long:**

```bash
str="Here is a list of functions  Marionette Recutils"
echo "${str/*  /}"   # <-- This way
# Out: Marionette Recutils
```

From `man bash` / **Parameter Expansion**

```
${parameter/pattern/string}

Pattern  substitution.   The pattern is expanded to produce a
pattern just as in pathname expansion, Parameter is  expanded
and  the  longest  match  of pattern against its value is re‐
placed with string.
```

Comment: Not good because in matches `"Here is a list of functions  "`, rather than the opposite match, namely `"  Marionette Recutils`.

Comment: Besides, I am working on using the character class `[:blank:]`.

Comment: @Randy There is no need to use `[:blank:]` here as you have said that the delimiter consists of two spaces. The `[:blank:]` class matches spaces or tabs. If you have the last part of the string in a variable, you can use that to delete it from the original string with `${str%"$endstr"}`. If you want to clarify the question, please do so by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

The confusing thing about character classes like `[:blank:]` is that they go *inside of* bracket expressions, so the whole thing has two concentric sets of brackets: `[[:blank:]]`. This also means you can combine them, like `[[:blank:][:lower:]]` (a single blank or lower-case letter) or `[-_[:alpha:]]` (a dash, underscore, or letter), or negate them like `[^[:blank:]]` (any character that *isn't* a blank).

So, you could use something like this:

```
ptrn="[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*"
echo "${str%$ptrn}"
```

or just:

```
echo "${str%[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*}"
```

Comment: It is not too confusing if one notes that the character class is `[:class:]`.  For `0123456789` the character class would be `[:digit:]`.  Thus the equivalent to `[0123456789]` is `[[:digit:]]`.

Comment: @Randy, on some systems, `[[:digit:]]` matches more than 0123456789 like the decimal digits in other decimal numeric systems